# Is there a smartpy util to stringify JSON?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I see there's a good utils repo for strings here:

https://github.com/RomarQ/tezos-sc-utils

I'm just wondering whether there's one for stringifying JSON. Or an example that does this.

Input: map or array of maps
Output: String or bytes

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such an operation would be unnecessarily expensive. I am not aware of any existing utility like that.

Comment: Would it still be expensive if it was within an offchain view and it only had to do it for a couple of fields?

Comment: for the Endless Ways `token_metadata` off-chain view i basically ended up assembling fragments of pre-baked JSON strings. unfortunately there is very little support or interest from the tools devs to support this kind of use-case, even though it is obviously important for non-trivial NFT contracts. sigh.

Comment: @damian, I'm working on a util for it so others can use on their offchain view. Any chance you could link to the code where you're doing this? I'm curious to see how you did it and what metadata you included.

Comment: @JJJ it's kinda complicated  DM me on twitter https://twitter.com/EndlessWays_TZ or join our discord (link in Twitter bio) and i'd be happy to share what i'm doing